# Export entire firebase realtime database with function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a firebase function that returns a json dump of my entire firebase database (or even just the /Reports node). Why does the below just return a blank?

```
app.get('/export', (req, res) => {

   var db = admin.database();
   var fullDataDump;

 db.ref('Reports').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    fullDataDump = snapshotToArray(snapshot);
});

return res.status(200).json(fullDataDump);

});

function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
      var returnArr = [];

      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;

          returnArr.push(item);
      });

      return returnArr;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase (and pretty much any modern web API) asynchronously. By the time you send the response, the data hasn't returend from Firebase yet.

That's the reason why you have to specify a callback to Firebase when you register your listener: that way Firebase can invoke your code once it's done loading the data.

The solution is to move the code that sends the response to the client *into* the callback:

```
app.get('/export', (req, res) => {

   var db = admin.database();
   var fullDataDump;

 db.ref('Reports').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    fullDataDump = snapshotToArray(snapshot);
    res.status(200).json(fullDataDump);
});


});

function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
  var returnArr = [];

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var item = childSnapshot.val();
      item.key = childSnapshot.key;

      returnArr.push(item);
  });

  return returnArr;
};
```

You'll note that I also changed `on('value'` to `once('value'`, since you're only interested in getting the data one time.